# Identity on a primary key column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have created an `Employee` table with the following columns and constraints:

```
EmpId(Primary Key, Identity(1,1),not null)
EmpName
EmpJob
etc.
```

Then I tried to insert `Employee` values from an aspx page through ADO.NET, unfortunately it had generated a wrong sequence of `EmpId` of `Employee` and the sequence is

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 9 17 18.
```

I don't know why it is behaving like that, so please help me.

Comment: Hard to explain without seeing any code. If you deleted any users that would explain the gaps since the old id's won't normally be reused.

Comment: sorry....its just a Inserting program, I hasn't deleted anything

Comment: [Stop making assumptions about `IDENTITY`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-making-assumptions-about-identity), stop worrying about gaps - they are really **NOT** a problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity isn't guaranteed to be without gaps in the sequence. It shouldn't be used for that because of this. 
Situations like cancelled/roll-backed queries and/or deleted entries will create gaps in the sequence.

Identity is used to provide a "unique" id in terms of concurrent transactions based on the current 'seed' value. 
But it does not guarantee no gaps (entires can be deleted, queries can be rolled back), uniqueness across multiple transactions (as the seed can change) or similar.

If you want to have an unbroken sequence of integers, you'll have to maintain it yourself after each insert/update/delete of entries.
But generally speaking - such a sequence shouldn't be needed for most any situation because more often then not you would merely be interested in the ordering/relative position when using identity as ordering (for example).

Comment: I tried to insert so many times because my connectionstring was not properly defined ,so do you think this is the problem?

Comment: could be many things, but generally speaking - its not a problem that there are gaps in your data. It's quite normal